# Had win7 and Ubuntu 16.01 on separate drives - downgraded to ubuntu 14.01 and now win7 isnt appearing in Grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I have 2 separate SSDs - one with windows 7 and the other with Ubuntu 14.04. I originally installed Ubuntu 16.01 on one drive and then Windows 7 on the next. When I did this, grub picked up the windows boot location and I could access it. I was having issues with 16.01 so I decided to downgrade to 14.04 and when I did so, I lost the option to boot my windows drive. No matter which drive I try to boot from, windows does not appear in Grub. I ran boot repair and I produced the summary below in which it appears to see windows 7. I am still new to Ubuntu and I have seen other questions like this asked, but the solution provided didn't work for me... or I did it wrong. I was hoping someone could provide some insight on this issue.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/17505326/

I ran

```
sudo update-grub
```

and it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have an UEFI motherboard with Ubuntu installed in UEFI mode. This is good.

You have Windows installed in Legacy mode. This is bad.

You can only boot one or the other, and it appears GRUB is installed to be used in UEFI mode. So you cannot boot a Legacy mode operating system from UEFI-mode GRUB IIRC.

to get truly seamless dual-boot you'll need to either:

Reinstall Windows in UEFI mode (or convert it to UEFI mode, but that's a bit more involved).

Or reinstall Ubuntu in legacy mode.

I recommend having everything running in UEFI mode and disabled the "Legacy Boot Option ROM" setting in the UEFI setup. This will make your computer boot much much faster, and initializes your graphics card and sometimes even networking much sooner (and faster). (ASUS motherboards are my only experience in this regard, non-asus YMMV)

In the mean time, to boot Windows, reboot into your UEFI firmware setup, and boot manually by selecting the `WD5000AAKX` disk on your system.

PS your encypted LUKS partition is not strong enough. Consider using stronger encryption options. See: [here](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#5-security-aspects)

Comment: Just FYI, the LUKS weakness is that you're using the default sha1 instead of sha512 for the hash.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to reinstall grub. follow this guide
http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Comment: Link is broken: `Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL` and saying follow this tutorial isn't a useful answer. See [How to write a good answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer).